# Search engine. Using asp.net and retrieving data from MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, search, gridview

I"m trying to make a search engine linked with mysql in asp.net . I want that the user can type a word/number and press search and he will see all rows in my database that contain that specific word.

at the first load page i'm getting full data from my database (as needed) than for exmple i try to search for "respect" and i click on button search(Zoeken) and nothing happens.

I've tried adding a label that changes after clicking on the button to see if the code is being executed after i press the button and it works it changes.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace KnowledgebaseKNO
{
public partial class Know : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridLaden();
        }


    }

    protected void GridLaden()
    {

        //start
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 127.0.0.1; user id = secret; persistsecurityinfo = True; database = knbase;pwd=secretinfo");
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblafspraken"))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //eind


    }


    protected void GridLadenSpecifiek()
    {
        string keywoord;

        keywoord = txt_zoekwoord.Text;


        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 127.0.0.1; user id = secret; persistsecurityinfo = True; database = knbase;pwd=secretinfo");
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT IDafspraak, NaamAfspraak,BeschrijvingAfspraak FROM tblafspraken where NaamAfspraak like '%" + keywoord + "%' or BeschrijvingAfspraak like '%" + keywoord + "%'"))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        lbl_test.Text = "Done!";



    }


    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void btn_Zoeken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridLadenSpecifiek();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remove the IsPostBack logic in btn event and in specific method. Leave it only in the Page_Load event

Comment: And parameratize your queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as it is now.

Comment: Steve: Removing IsPostBack was helpful but my page is still not reloading.

Comment: VDWWD: Thanks for your advice, i'll parametrize them for sure, but after solving the problem with retrieving the needed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the data in the grid view. I think you can use javascript to show the rows having the words that is present in the text box. I think that is better solution as you are bringing all the data at page load it self.

Now coming to your question. Removing

```
 if (!this.IsPostBack)
```

code block should make your code work.